# How can i delete selected data from database using jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

please help me..this is my fisrt code in jsp,i do not know how to do it right

```
<body>
    <%
         String sid = request.getParameter("u_id");
         try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","M0hdZ@k1");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("delete from information where id = '"+sid+ "'");
            ps.executeUpdate();
            con.close();
            ps.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
         {
           out.println(ex.getMessage());
          }
    %>
    <h1>Record Deleted...</h1><br>
           <center><a href="Admin.jsp">Go Back</a></center>
```

Comment: what's the problem there and what are you getting as error ?

Comment: Firstly,This code logic should be part of a java file.What errors logs do you face in server console?